# How can I get the full url link of of Pages library via rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there a way to get the link to pages in a Page library?
Cant find a property that stores the url?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=File/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=File


/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText


/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<list url>')/Files?$select=ServerRelativeUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

Pages library is in a way a document library.

So, get full link of the page in the Pages library, you can use the `EncodedAbsUrl` property.

The REST API implementation for that would be as below:

```
https://site-collection-url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl
```

Comment: hi @naijacoder, did you try the above REST endpoint ?

Comment: hey @naijacoder,  if it helped you, could you please mark it as answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web with publishing feature activated, the pages url is stored in the property bag at the web at the key "vti_pageslistname"

Comment: Thanks but i don't get to see this property in my rest api result